# UITableView rounded corners the first and last one problem when refreshing the table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift4.2

I used UITableView and set rounded corners for the first and last cell successfully, But if I want to refresh the table (Pull to Refresh) and there is a new cell the table will be like the picture.

How to clear the cached rounded corner cells and fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Simply set rounded corner for tableview, no need to 1st and last cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) on that formerly last row.